# Why have my DevTools stopped displaying my IndexedDB?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, dexie

I am creating what I thought was a simple set of DB tables in Dexie:

`class ClientCache extends Dexie {

```
messages!: Dexie.Table<Message, string>;
clientSettings!: Dexie.Table<ClientSettingType, string>;
characterSync!: Dexie.Table<CharacterSyncType, EphemeraCharacterId>;

constructor() {
    super("maketheworlddb")
    this.version(1).stores({
        clientSettings: 'key,value',
        messages: 'MessageId,CreatedTime,Target',
        characterSync: 'CharacterId'
    })
}
```

}`

This general structure has been working wonderfully for me now for years, but today I added the characterSync table, and now for some reason the Chrome DevTools won't show me the database any more.

It's very peculiar:  I can bring up the Storage tab in the DevTools, and see a couple hundred kB assigned to "IndexedDB" storage, but the actual IndexedDB tab on the tools has nothing in it.

If I access a different site that has an IndexedDB, those DBs show up.  Just not mine.

Everything still *works*, all the data is there, and my application is fetching and writing it just fine ... but I already miss my DevTool access.

Does anyone have any experience with this kind of thing?  What can I possibly have done to create this state, and what can I do to get out of it?

As I'd been developing, I'd added new versions of the DB in the constructor, so originally I added a "this.version(5)" definition which added the characterSync table to the definitions already existing.  The DevTools disappeared, so I started trying to simplify.

I cleared all my IndexedDB storage (from the Clear Site button on the Storage tab, since I can't access anything on the IndexedDB tab) to get rid of any possible corrupt condition, and regenerated using the five-step version.  I expected the DevTools access to reappear, but it did not.

I reduced the five-step dexie constructor to a single step, cleared my IndexedDB storage.  I expected the DevTools access to reappear, but it did not.

I rebuilt my dexie constructor to explicitly execute a full DB delete before attempting to reconstruct.  I hoped the DevTools access would reappear, but it did not.

Answer (score 0):

And now, with literally no change in the code (just having restarted my machine, and therefore (I presume) the Chromium engine), the previous behavior is restored.

A little bit frustrating, but I'll take it.  I wish I could post more about reproducing the error, so we might sort it out, but my system no longer reproduces.